# How do I get the picture of a country from its name using python?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to build a website that is similar to worldle, except that it allows you to play unlimited times. I have a list of all the countries in the world, but I want to be able to get the picture of the country once I randomly select a country. Is there a library or API that allows me to do this, or do I have to manually download a picture of every country?

Comment: How about checking out the project's github page: https://github.com/teuteuf/worldle The developer lists resources used, like https://github.com/djaiss/mapsicon

Comment: can i use his code?